# Writing a function name in a normal paragraph in my dissertation

Tags: writing-style, code

I want to mention the name of an specific function (or method) that I used in a experiment in a normal paragraph in my dissertation. What is the best way to do it? Considering that the official dissertation format that my teachers gave me doesn't mention how to do it.

For example:

> "... with the Java programming language we can use System.nanoTime ..."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is this a question regarding the formatting?

In this case I would use a typewriter font. In LaTeX this is simple by using `\texttt`:

```
... with the Java programming language we can use \texttt{System.nanoTime} ...
```

This looks similar to

> ... with the Java programming language we can use `System.nanoTime` ...

In Microsoft Word, you could simply use some font, such as Courier New.

However, you should check with your supervisor if this is OK for him or her.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding some info about the non-LaTeX scenario.

Comment: Or `\lstinline`, if you're using listings and have specific formatting set up for your functions.

Comment: Why `\texttt` rather than `\verb` (if not having the `listings` package included)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are some drawbacks related to \verb. 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt
I had quite a good experience with always using \texttt since it seems to be more reliable and versatile. Maybe this depends also on personal preferences.

Comment: @J-Kun on the contrary I'd say `\verb` is more reliable, in particular for anything source code related, since it never misinterprets symbols as LaTeX syntax. Particularly relevant to function/method names: it has no problem with underscores. Of course, the option to include LaTeX commands is why `\texttt` is more versatile indeed, but for source snippets that versatility is mostly a burden.